# Why are variables initialized to 0?

Tags: c++, variables

I just started studying C++ from an ebook.
I don't have any errors on my code but I do have a question.
The book uses the following code to sum up two numbers:

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    std::cout << "Enter two numbers:" << std::endl;
    int v1 = 0, v2 = 0;
    std::cin >> v1 >> v2;
    std::cout << "The sum of " << v1 << " and " << v2
        << " is " << v1 + v2 << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

So `int v1 = 0,v2 = 0;` is used for variables. 
Why are they initialized to 0?

Comment: They are initialised with a value of zero. Otherwise they would contain some random data.

Comment: because it's best practice to initialize your variables!

Comment: Why not zero? Do you have a preference for a particular number?

Comment: certain compiler will initialize them with `(int)0xcc...` for you, in Debug configs.

Comment: I was inclined to say "Because a variable should be something well-defined, and zero is as good as any other number", but actually zero is a _rather bad choice_. All numbers are equal, but some numbers aren't.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
int v1 = 0;
```

That's called *initialization* and it's a good habit to get in to. If you leave out the initializer for built in types, its value is called to be *indeterminate* and it's illegal to read such a value.

Let's suppose you do this:

```
int v1;
std::cin >> v1;
std::cout << v1;
```

Input operation in the second line can fail, for example if you enter a letter instead of a number, and `v1` will be left untouched. There is no check whether input succeeded and if `v1` still happens to uninitialized, bang! You've invoked undefined behaviour and you're left at the mercy of the compiler to do just about anything it wants.

In the code you posted, `v1` and `v2` are initialized and even if input fails, you'll at least get *some* result with well defined behaviour.

That said, it's a logical error to not check whether input suceeded. After all, `0` is a valid input possibilty and without an additional check there's no way to tell if that's what user entered.

The easiest way to do that is to use input expression in boolean context, inside `if` condition:

```
if (std::cin >> v1 >> v2) {
    // good, use v1 and v2
} else {
    // bad input, we can't
    // rely on v1 and v2 to
    // have meaninful value here
}
```

Streams are implicitly convertible to `bool` and if there are no error flags set, they evaluate to `true` and to `false` otherwise.

Having done the above check there's little to no need for initialization, as we'll never touch `v1` and `v2` if input failed.

Comment: Your example has nothing to do with initialization. If the read operation fails, the value of `v1` is indeterminate no matter if it was initialized or not.

Comment: @rubenbv Huh? I was talking about uninitializated variables. If you initialize a variable before you try to write to it via `operator>>` it'll be initialized even if `operator>>` fails. Its value may not be specified by the standard if that happens (or is it? check `27.7.2.2.2`), but there's no UB.

Comment: I'd appreciate feedback from downvoters (in light of now edited answer).

Comment: Didn’t downvote but I don’t agree – the initialisation is useless here, don’t do it. You make it sound like defensive coding but in reality it just hides a bug, namely the failure to check whether input succeeded. Only initialise variables with meaningful values, not with bogus placeholders.

Comment: I agree with @KonradRudolph, don't try to hide your bugs, fix them! But in the context of the initial code coming from a beginners Book you could say it's ok to do it like that in the beginning to don't get to complex to early, but it should get corrected later on. (Not a downvoter)

Comment: @KonradRudolph "but in reality it just hides a bug, namely the failure to check whether input succeeded" -- I disagree. That bug is just as apparent with or without the initialisation, and the initialisation limits the potential damage of that bug. `cin` should be checked, but the initialisation should only be removed *after* that check has been added.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Fair point, I mentioned that in answer. Stream input is actualy one of rare cases where there initialy isn't a meaningful value to initialize with.

Comment: BTW, the standard says, and GCC's implementation agrees, that `operator>>` always sets `v1` if some input is available, even if the input is not a number. However, if no input is available, `v1` retains its previous value.

Comment: @ManuelGörlich I thought I already explained that suggesting to put input in if statement.

Comment: @hvd “the initialisation limits the potential damage of that bug” – how so?

Comment: @KonradRudolph in that it prevents potential UB (I agree it's logicaly wrong).

Comment: @KonradRudolph Right, what jrok said. If the variables are initialised, the behaviour is wrong but predictable. If the variables are uninitialised, the behaviour (in practise: the value of `v1` and `v2`) is unpredictable.

Comment: @jrok While I’m all for preventing UB in general I disagree that it would cause “additional damage” in this specific case. This isn’t a situation where the compiler could *conceivably* exploit UB to generate invalid or dangerous code (because it’s not unconditionally UB) so the effect *will* for all intents and purposes be the same as a computation with a bogus value.

Comment: @KonradRudolph A real possibility is that with bogus `0` values, the sum doesn't make sense, but with bogus uninitialised values, the addition happens to overflow and aborts the entire program. (Which can admittedly of course also happen with large enough user input.)

Comment: @hvd See previous comment. To wit, while I am generally a big proponent of having predictable behaviour, in this specific situation this buys us *nothing*: the behaviour may be predictable but since we still don’t expect it in the code we cannot make use of that predictability. The overflow is *also* not possible – or rather, it would be just as possible with user-entered input.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Yes, I edited my comment to mention user input. About the uninitialised case, I'm a strong proponent of "always print 0" (or even "always print garbage") over "sometimes print garbage, sometimes crash", so I don't think we'll agree, but that's okay, if we agree on the best way to write the program, it actually doesn't really matter if we disagree on the second best way. :)

Comment: @hvd Actually regarding your last comment, I think you’re *objectively* wrong. It’s better for the application to crash than to continue running with a bogus value and silently yielding false results. Crashing at least lets the user know something’s wrong. But actually this won’t happen here anyway.

Comment: @KonradRudolph If I were able to edit my comment an hour later, I would edit it to say "(or even "always print garbage" or "always crash")" It's generally accepted that programs should behave predictably. And it's not generally accepted, but I do agree that a crash is generally better than going on doing the wrong thing. The only question is what to do when the two are in conflict. In that case, "doing the same wrong thing every time" wins it for me. About "But actually this won’t happen here anyway.": it depends on the compiler/options, but I can get it to crash on a "normal" system.

Comment: The real solution is to yell (and eventually fire) at the guy who wrote std::cin >> v1; without checking if it succeeded: if(std::cin >> v1). That said, you have a program behaving deterministically and initializing v1 is pointless and probably wrong.

Answer (score 22):

It’s [cargo cult programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming). It isn’t actively harmful but it serves no real benefit here and is likely only done because either the author wants to simplify a concept for teaching purposes, or because he misunderstood something.

Here’s why.

*Normally*, all variables should be directly initialised once declared. This ensures that the variable is never in an indeterminate state. This makes the control flow simpler, the code easier to reason about and as a consequence prevents bugs.

But this only makes sense if we can initialise the variables with a *meaningful* value – i.e. with the value it’s meant to represent later. In your code, this isn’t the case – rather, the variables get their value assigned later, via input streaming (unfortunately C++ doesn’t support a concise, canonical way of *initialising* a variable with a value read from input).

As @jrok said, the initialisation ostensibly guards against invalid inputs and subsequent errors in the code. I say *ostensibly* because that’s not actually true: the value we initialised the variables with – `0` – is *also* invalid in the context of the program so we haven’t actually gained anything.

Jack Aidley offers that the real reason for this code is to prevent a compiler warning. But no compiler should warn here, for the reason outlined above. And in fact, GCC *doesn’t* warn, even when compiled with lots of warnings enabled. Maybe other compilers do but I would consider this warning noise.

Comment: Agreed, something like `int foo << cin;` would've been pretty cool but alas, it's not possible to do so in C++, so you're left with delayed initialization as your only choice...

Comment: @Thomas Actually I was thinking more of `auto i = read<int>(cin);` which is readily feasible  as a library solution. `read` would either return a value akin to `boost::optional` or the function could throw an exception on failure (but the first variant has many advantages). In fact, whenever my code heavily relies on IO, I use such functions throughout.

Answer (score 13):

It's a common practice, but in this example it's a workaround for not having thought enough about error handling. The rationalization that you could get an invalid value if you don't initialize them only matters if you don't bother to check whether the input succeeded. The code doesn't check whether the input succeeded, so it is fatally flawed. No amount of otherwise unneeded initialization can fix that.

```
std::cin >> v1 >> v2;
if (std::cin)
    std::cout << "The sum of " << v1 << " and " << v2
        << " is " << v1 + v2 << std::endl;
else
    std::cout << "Bogus input\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a common practice to set a value to the variables when you define them. 
Sometimes, you get bad errors when try to operate with variables that weren't initializated with a value.

But in your example, it isn't important, because you set a value with cin read.

Comment: No, it is important. `std::istream::operator>>` could fail.

Comment: @Jeffrey no, it's not. I'd be important to check the values after reading from stdin and query the user again if it failed.

Comment: @ManuelGörlich, you would be important? What does it mean?

Comment: sorry, should be 'It would be important'

Comment: @ManuelGörlich, also what would be exactly the value to check for an error here?

Comment: See @Pete Becker answer

Comment: @ManuelGörlich, "I'd be important to check the values after reading from stdin and query the user again if it failed". This answer doesn't say so. Actually it says that nothing matters because the variable is set by `cin`. That's the whole point of me downvoting it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34766/discussion-between-jeffrey-and-manuel-gorlich)

Answer (score 0):

While the other answers are correct, I don't believe they are likely to be the actual reason why these variables are being initialised to zero.

Instead, I strongly suspect the reason is this: if they were not, most compilers would issue a warning about using an uninitialised variable. I believe the initialisation here is there primarily, or purely, to suppress the issuing of a warning.

Comment: name at least one compiler which will yield a warning here

Answer (score -1):

It's part of a common practice.

It is better to initialize a value to a variable to give it a sense of completeness.

Comment: No, it's not better. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18030997/why-are-variables-initialized-to-0/18031043#comment26378958_18031043).